# jinja2 UndefinedError: 'individual_page' is undefined

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to get inside each individual post that is made by a user by.

```
@blogs.route('/individual_set/<int:set_id>')
def individual_set(set_id):
    individual_page = Set.query.get_or_404(set_id)
    return render_template('forms_page.html', individual_page = 
    individual_page)
```

Here Set is the database model with id, title, content, and other things.
However when I try to get to the page where the posts are rendered by using a for loop.. I get the error saying **individual_page** is undefined. Whereas I am defining the **individual_page** above.

And a thing I did is that I tried to access the **/individual_page/1** directly. It was working. It is not working whenever I try to access the HTML page below.
Here is the page where each set is rendered.

```
      {% for each_set in sets %}
      <a href="{{url_for('blogs.individual_set',set_id = 
      individual_page.id)}}"></a>
      <div class="practice-set shover">
        <p class="practice-set-index">{{each_set.id}}</p>
        <div class="line-set"></div>
        <p class="set-content-text">{{each_set.title}}</p>
        <p class="set-plan">{{each_set.price}}</p>
      </div>
      </a>
      {% endfor %}
```

This is the query of all sets. And the moment I try to get to **/set_page**.
The error is shown.

```
@blogs.route('/set_page')
def set_page():
    sets = Set.query.order_by(Set.date_posted.desc())
    return render_template('sets_page.html',sets = sets)
```

This is the HTML snippet responsible for the redirection to /set_page

```
      <a
        href="{{url_for('blogs.set_page')}}"
        class="index-card-btn btn-primary"
        >Continue
      </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something problematic in this code:

```
@blogs.route('/ind_set/<int:set_id>')
def ind_set(set_id):
    ind_set= Set.query.get_or_404(set_id)
    return render_template('forms_page.html',ind_set=ind_set)
```

Your function is named ind_set and has a route defined, but you redefine it to something else on the very next line:

```
ind_set= Set.query.get_or_404(set_id)
```

So the fix is to either rename the function or the variable so they won't clash. In fact I would recommend renaming both - use more descriptive names for your variables and functions.

Comment: Yes sir, I did what you are saying but not luck.. I have updated the question

Comment: I find it surprising that a URL like /individual_page/1 works if your route is defined as: `@blogs.route('/individual_set/<int:set_id>')`. I believe there is still confusion between function names and route names ? Are you sure you don't have more routes in your code ? And `<a href={{url_for('blogs.individual_set',set_id = individual_page.id)}}"></a>` should probably be: `<a href={{ url_for('blogs.individual_set', set_id=each_set.id) }}"></a>` - like you did in the lines that follow.